# Simple .exe using 50% CPU using System.Threading

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I have a very simple executable that check a specific folder about every 3 seconds to see if there is a file(s) in there.  If it finds a file(s) it does something and then returns to checking the folder every 3 seconds.

People have reported that at times this executable is taking up 50% of their CPU, is there any suggestions on how do this properly.  Below is sample code of how I am doing this.

```
// Check our folder every x seconds
Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, Global.SecondsToCheckPrintFolder * 1000);
```

Comment: Consider to use `FileSystemWatcher` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Could you post the callback as well?

Answer (score 9):

You should use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

To answer your question, your main thread is probably running `while(true) { }`, which will kill the CPU forever.

To make the main thread wait forever, you should call `Application.Run()`.
You could also call `Thread.Sleep(-1)`.

Comment: I also had no idea this class existed...I will give it a shot.
How often does it check the folder?  And can that be specified?

Comment: @Adam: It uses registers for change notifications.

Answer (score 1):

This executes inside a thread pool, which means that the callback can be executed multiple simultaneous times. Why not use a simple loop, like so?

```
while(true)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"someFile"))
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```